# Formatting numbers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I recorded a macro to convert a csv file to columns.
I cannot format the two columns with numbers. I tried recording several scenarios and adding different commands.

The data looks like this:

Before Formatting
[image]

After Formatting
[image]

My code works for Text to Columns:

```vb
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"),DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
  :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5,   1), Array(6, 1), _
  Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("E:F").Select
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=","
```

I’ve tried recording whilst I format the cells using keyboard shortcuts, and an attempt to write some coding; amongst others:

```
'NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"

Columns("E:F").Value = Columns("E:F").Value

With Range("E:F")
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I’m working on a Danish keyboard.

Comment: You should be able to use the macro recorder to capture you applying number formatting using the format > number > ..... or format > custom if in the sheet you can make the numbers appear as you wish. Ignoring the code side, are you able to format the numbers in the sheet in the way you want? Also, i can't really work out from the picture but looks like some kind of "pixillation"?

Comment: Thx QHarr. Yes i have tried recording different conversion methodes but they stil do not work when running the macro again.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `.value=val(.value)` instead of `.Value = .Value` and if it did not work, change the format line to `.NumberFormat = "General"` if it did not work, you need to loop through cells one by one and convert them to Numbers, below code will definitely work.

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumbers()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet 'change as needed

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rng
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                cell.NumberFormat = "General"
                cell.Value = Val(cell.Value)
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Ibo for your comment. This still does not work. I think it might have to do with either wondows settings or my local settings.

Comment: can you upload your workbook or a sample of your data? I am sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.Value = .Value
```

use

```
.TextToColumns
```

Example:

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"
Columns("A:A").TextToColumns
```

This work for entire range instantly and does not need run in a loop for single cells by cells.